# Visual Studio Team Services when someone leaves the company

Tags: visual-studio, azure, tfs, azure-devops

We've transitioning from Rackspace dedicated boxes to a completely cloud Azure environment.  Production servers and development and as an MS shop we're going to be using Visual Studio Team Services.  As an MS ISV partner we have a bunch of MSDN seats so our developers are all going to have an MSDN w/ VS Premium account which we'll use with Team Services/TFS.  We're replicating our production web server on a virtual machine but after some refactoring will eventually move to an Azure website.

My question is about when users leave the company.  Right now we have everyone log into a development server using RDP.  They develop on that server.  When someone is gone we shut their access off to that server.

With Team Services when the user opens up a project do they automatically get the entire project downloaded to their local development environment/machine?  If someone leaves the company is there a process using VSO that secures that code and removes it from them or makes it inaccessible?  Any way to lock it down when we need to?  I can't seem to find a procedure to do this.

Comment: You handle IP theft through legal channels if it comes up. If you're really concerned about someone stealing your source code, make every developer work in an isolated room with security guards posted outside to make sure they don't bring anything into the room that they're not authorized to have, including camera phones, and to make sure they don't remove anything from the room.

Comment: Agreed, treating developers like criminals will not get the results that you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add or remove someone from the account, go to the Users hub on the home page for your account. If you remove a user from it, that user will no longer be able to access your account.

When users connect to your account, they'll need to take some action to get source code. That would be cloning in the case of using Git or creating a workspace and running get for TFVC.

If the user has source code, for example, on a machine, there is no way to remotely remove it. They won't be able to get updates, etc., but there's nothing running on the computer that would be able to erase the code the user has already obtained.

Answer (score 0):

All source code sharing i know allow zipping up or browsing the local repository. Including VS Team Services.

Daniel Mann is correct . Developing on shared servers via RDP is terrible for productivity due to development being graphics and disk intensive, often requiring admin rights and reboots / crashes, debugging triggers system interrupts, out of memory loops are fun on a shared machine  ie they  stuff everybody else around. (Even with RDP you can copy and paste or map a network drive locally or upload to the net )

If your doing critical stuff the ONLY thing that really works is  physically bring them in to non internet connected machine /network with USB disabled.  However these mechanisms especially denying internet will half productivity.

This is why most organizations rely on legal contracts. On a 2M project is it worth making it a 4M project?  There are cases where this is required normally around national security /CIA / Defence but not for IP, there are better / trickier ways.

Pretty much all binaries are reverse engineer-able with little effort if you really want to.  obfuscation does very little.